# Ubuntu 16.04 boot as init=/root/init.sh and exec init 3 in shell, but why X11 started?

Tags: boot, grub2, bash, kernel, init

Ubuntu 16.04.5 default environment.

I want to do some custom job before init. grub.cfg as

`linux    /boot/vmlinuz ... ro init=/root/init.sh`

init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some task
exec init 3
```

after boot, X started.

if grub 
`linux    /boot/vmlinuz ... ro init=/root/init.sh 3`,can success boot into text mode.

according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html , 3 is not a kernel’s command-line parameters, kernel will pass it as an argument to init, here is /root/init.sh.

change /root/init.sh to :

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some task
echo $1
sleep 3s
exec init 3
```

I can see the value passed from kernel.

In my submission，no matter what value grub -> kernel -> /root/init.sh , I will discard the value and exec init as runlevel 3. why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

according to poettering's response to my issue at systemd: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10752

> we generally read /proc/cmdline, not argv[], since the kernel removes some bits from the latter that we need to know. We essentially ignore argv[] altogether.
>
> Hence, what you are trying to do doesn't work, you'd have to overmount /proc/cmdline instead with some file with the new arguments.

about 'overmount', according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364442/cant-mount-on-proc-cmdline/364448 ,

1. make a copy of `/proc/cmdline` at `/root/cmdline`
2. add `3` at the end of `/root/cmdline`
3. run command `mount -n --bind -o ro /root/cmdline /proc/cmdline`
4. run command `exec init`

now system will boot with runlevel 3.

In summary, change /root/init.sh to

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some task
cp /proc/cmdline /root/cmdline
sed -i.bck '$s/$/ 3/' /root/cmdline
mount -n --bind -o ro /root/cmdline /proc/cmdline
exec init
```

system will boot into text mode after custom job finish as I except.